# Paste command to command mode instead of insert mode

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste

I observed a difference in behavior between Vim and Neovim: When pasting
a `:`-prefixed command in *normal* mode, Vim will enter command mode
whereas Neovim will enter insert mode. More precisely:

- Given the selection buffer contents `:echo "foo"` (e. g. `printf ':echo "foo"' |xsel`),
- and Vim/Neovim running in a terminal and currently in normal mode,
- then when pasting the selection buffer with middle click or `<S-Insert>`
- Vim will enter command mode and paste the contents there,
- Neovim will enter insert mode at the current cursor position and paste the contents there.

(FWIW I have `set mouse=` in both, but as stated above the behavior
is the same using the keyboard. Both Vim and Neovim are in `nopaste`
state.)

*I strongly prefer the Vim behavior* as there’s more convenient ways of
pasting into the buffer. Is there a way to make Neovim behave the same
as Vim when pasting?

Comment: Good question. I'm trying to find which function in vim is called when something is pasted from the outside (with gdb). It's hard cause the paste-related functions in vim and nvim aren't named the same. vim has `bracketed_paste` (which isn't the one responsible for pasting from the outside, btw); nvim has `handle_bracketed_paste`.

Comment: In theory, NeoVim's behavior is safer. On macOS + Vim, `echo ':echo "foo"' | pbcopy`, `vim`, Cmd-V leaves me with the command and a blank line in the buffer and in Normal mode. (This sounds closer to your NeoVim behavior, and may or may not have been affected by bracketed paste.)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `Shift-Insert` to insert the marked text, use Vim registers. So first copy your line using a yank command like `0y$` and then use `:CTRL-R0` to paste it into the command line.

Note: depending on how you yanked it, you may need to remove the trailing Linefeed. This happens e.g. when using `yy` to yank a complete line.

See [:h c_CTRL-R](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R)

Comment: That’s an option when your hands are already at the keyboard but as I wrote I’m using the mouse selection as well so your suggestion introduces one more annyoing back-and-forth between mouse and keyboard. In contrast, middle-click paste works consistently pretty much everywhere *except* Nvim.

Comment: Well, first of all, `<Shift-Insert>` is received by the terminal, so vim/nvim does not know  this is a paste action. So you need to disable bracketed paste mode. I don't know how to do this in nvim, for Vim you can set the terminal option `t_BE` to empty. I don't know nvim enough. And then finally if there is no other way, try to change the way you are yanking and pasting to achieve your goal.